# Can you explain in English, as simply as possible, what a copy constructor is and when I need to use it

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm a programmer who has primarily worked in Python switching over to C++. I'm getting the hang of pointers and memory allocation, but I've read several explanations of copy constructors, and I do not understand what they are.

Can you explain, what a copy constructor is and when I need to use one?

Comment: When you need to make a copy of your object in a way that the default one doesn't handle.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz how is this a duplicate? The question you referenced is a list of book recommendations. I have a specific conceptual programming questions.

Comment: That popped up as a first suggested link, and I found it too funny to not use it. Mainly because your problem is easily googleable and isn't a problem, but instead asking for reference about most basic concept.

Comment: It's needed because C++ and some other languages try to pretend that heavyweight objects are really "scalars" that can be assigned directly to variables, vs being passed by reference.  I'll agree that it's a challenge to get your head around this without having your head explode.

Comment: @HotLicks as much as you pretend you know anything about the subject, I presume. The fact that all managed languages use pointers doesn't mean it's impossible to pass a stack-allocated object.

Comment: Also with Rule Of Zero things get simpler, not harder to understand; people saying it's hard are usually the people spreading nonsense about pointers.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/

> #### What is a copy constructor?
>
> A copy constructor is a special constructor for a class/struct that is used to make a copy of an existing instance. According to the C++ standard, the copy constructor for MyClass must have one of the following signatures:
>
> ```
> MyClass( const MyClass& other );
> MyClass( MyClass& other );
> MyClass( volatile const MyClass& other );
> MyClass( volatile MyClass& other );
> ```
>
> #### When do I need to write a copy constructor?
>
> First, you should understand that if you do not declare a copy constructor, the compiler gives you one implicitly. The implicit copy constructor does a member-wise copy of the source object.
>
> `[...]`
>
> In many cases, this is sufficient. However, there are certain circumstances where the member-wise copy version is not good enough. By far, the most common reason the default copy constructor is not sufficient is because the object contains raw pointers and you need to take a "deep" copy of the pointer. That is, you don't want to copy the pointer itself; rather you want to copy what the pointer points to.

Comment: Let me google that for you, huh?

Comment: Why rollback? I make the post looks more presentable, and remove the line that refers to something that you didn't quote.

Comment: The signatures part got left out, but a copy constructor for class Foo should just take a "const Foo & foo" as its only parameter

Comment: @bdwain That won't bind to lvalues, will it?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz i had a typo and put 2 &'s in. Is that what you're referencing?

Comment: @bdwain yes, because the previous code was valid, but totally different.

Comment: yea just a typo. my bad